# Realtek 8818 wifi adapter won't Activate

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

My windows 10 pc is showing the usb dongle just fine, but the wifi is deactivated... if i try to activate it via `Settings -> Network & Internet -> Wifi`, it just keeps spinning. What should i do?

Details:
- I was able to get a cable and update the drivers
- Windows is 100% updated
- No erros appear, it just spins...

Comment: Have you tried in any other machine?

Comment: Hoe does it shows in device manager?

Comment: @MichaelBay yes, it does... shows up perfectly... name, driver version, etc...

Comment: @vembutech i dont have another...